# Where do I find the ODE.m package of the Book "Scientific Computing with Mathematica®" by Marasco and Romano?

Tags: packages

I downloaded this [book](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0151-9) at SpringerLink. It should contain a CD-ROM with notebook-files (i.e. ODE.m) but there is no download available.

Particularly I am interested in a *Mathematica* package which solves an ODE with periodic solution (limit cycle) by the Lindstedt-Poincaré method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the *Mathematica*-Files [here](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780817642051), respectively [Updated Mathematica 5 supplementary note](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/Mathematica+5_supplementary+notebooks_978-0-8176-4205-1.zip?SGWID=0-0-45-918837-p2118124), [Updated Mathematica 6 supplementary note](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/Mathematica+6_supplementary+notebooks_978-0-8176-4205-1.zip?SGWID=0-0-45-918838-p2118124).

On Pages from http://link.springer.com, search for **Additional links** or **Downloads**, this usually leads to additional materials.

[image]

Comment: In general, for Springer-Verlag books, [this site](http://extras.springer.com/) is where you can access the supplementary material.